# Color picking wide lines on 1x1 viewport not working in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

With color picking I'm running into a weird issue after switching from a Geforce to a Radeon card.

The line width is 6. The problem is: If the line is parallel to the viewport's x or y axis, it behaves as if it was only 1 pixel wide. If the line is at an angle, it's working fine. So for example, if the line runs from (10, 12) to (110, 12) it doesn't work (parallel to x axis), but if it runs from (10, 12) to (110, 13) it's working fine.

Normal rendering is always working fine.

The difference is that for color picking I'm only rendering a 1x1 viewport. If I render a full viewport for picking, everything is working. So my guess is that the clipping doesn't handle these corner cases correctly.

Will post code upon request, but considering how specific the error case is I doubt it's going to be useful. Did anybody ever run into an issue like this?

Comment: Downvote and close vote, but no comment. What's the issue?

Comment: So you are basically rendering a line, where the actual line center is out of the viewport, but due to the line width, your hope that your viewport pixel is still affected by it? If that worked on the Geforce, you are quite lucky, because OpenGL's clipping rules don't require that to work at all. OTOH, wide lines are deprecated anyway, you are probably best off just drawing them as rectangles, which will also work with clipping.

Comment: @derhass Alright. I just thought it was odd that it's mostly working, except in this seemingly specific case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The difference is that for color picking I'm only rendering a 1x1 viewport.

Vertices are clipped to be within the viewport. So if a line is partially in the viewport, then the vertices are clipped to be fully within the viewport.

If the line is *fully outside* the viewport, then the OpenGL specification states that the line will be *discarded*. The width of the line is *not* taken into account.

NVIDIA's implementation has always played fast-and-loose with this. AMD's is more strict, but clearly it sometimes works for you. But by the specification, it shouldn't work at all unless the line is actually inside of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

The 4.5 spec says:

> 13.5 Primitive Clipping
>
> [...]If the primitive is a line segment, then clipping does nothing to it if it lies entirely within the clip volume, and discards it if it lies entirely outside the volume.
>
> If part of the line segment lies in the volume and part lies outside, then the line segment is clipped and new vertex coordinates are computed for one or both vertices. A clipped line segment endpoint lies on both the original line segment and the boundary of the clip volume.
>
> This clipping produces a value, 0 ≤ t ≤ 1, for each clipped vertex. If the
>   coordinates of a clipped vertex are P and the original vertices’ coordinates are P₁ and P₂, then t is given by
>
> ```
>                           P = t∙P₁ + (1 - t)∙P₂.
> ```
>
> The value of t is used to clip vertex shader outputs as described in section 13.5.1.